# Balanced expression with replacement

Tags: python, oop, recursion, stack, brackets

Given a string that contains only the following => ‘{‘, ‘}’, ‘(‘, ‘)’, ‘[’, ‘]’. At some places there is ‘X’ in place of any bracket. Determine whether by replacing all ‘X’s with appropriate bracket, is it possible to make a valid bracket sequence.

Examples:

```
Input : S = "{(X[X])}"  
Output : Balanced

Input : S = "[{X}(X)]"  
Output : Not balanced
```

I tried to work it out like this, and it works for examples above. But it doesn't work for all examples eg. (it should be balanced but it says it's not)

```
Input: S = "([X}])"   
Output: Not balanced
```

I tried to work it out but i can't find a solution. Please help.

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def insert(self, x):
        self.data.append(x)

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.data) == 0

    def remove(self):
        if self.empty(): 
            raise ValueError('Stack is empty.')
        self.data.pop()

    def top_element(self):
        if self.empty(): 
            raise ValueError('Stack is empty.')
        return self.data[-1]

def is_matching(a, b):
    if a == "(" and b == ")":
        return True
    elif a == "[" and b == "]":
        return True
    elif a == "{" and b == "}":
        return True
    elif a == "X":
        return True
    return False

def is_balanced(expression,elements=Stack(),ind=0):
    if ind == len(expression):
        return elements.empty()

    pre_brackets = "([{" 
    post_brackets = ")]}" 

    char = expression[ind] 

    if char in pre_brackets: 
        elements.insert(char) 
        return is_balanced(expression,elements,ind+1)

    elif char in post_brackets: 
        if elements.empty() :
            return False  
        if not is_matching(elements.top_element(), char):
            return False
        elements.remove()
        return is_balanced(expression,elements,ind+1)

    elif char == "X":
        temp = Stack()
        temp.insert(char)
        result = (is_balanced(expression,temp,ind+1))
        if result: 
            return True
        if elements.empty():
            return False  
        elements.remove()
        return is_balanced(expression,elements,ind+1)

expression = "([X}])"

if expression == "": 
    print("No brackets in expression!")
elif len(expression) % 2 != 0: 
    print("Not balanced")
elif is_balanced(expression):
    print("Balanced")
else:
    print("Not Balanced")
```

Comment: How exactly do you balance `{(X[X])}`?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I think if you make the first `X` a `[` and the second a `]` it balances, i.e. `{([[]])}`.

Comment: Please don't delete questions without any reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final improved and optimised version that works:

```
class Sklad:

def __init__(self):
    self.podatki = []
    
def vstavi(self, x):
    self.podatki.append(x)
def prazen(self):
    return len(self.podatki) == 0

def odstrani(self):
    if self.prazen(): 
        raise ValueError('ODSTRANI: Sklad je prazen.')
    self.podatki.pop()

def vrh(self):
    if self.prazen(): 
        raise ValueError('VRH: Sklad je prazen.')
    return self.podatki[-1]

def __str__(self):
    izp = 'DNO'
    for elt in self.podatki: 
        izp += ' : ' + str(elt)
    return izp + ' : VRH'

def kopiraj(self):
    if self.prazen(): 
        raise ValueError('VRH: Sklad je prazen.')
    obrnjen = Sklad()
    nov = Sklad()
    for elt in self.podatki: 
        obrnjen.vstavi(elt)
    for elt in self.podatki: 
        nov.vstavi(elt)
    return nov



def so_pravilno(izraz, hrani = None, nivo = 0, oklep = {"(":")","[":"]","{":"}"}):

    if not hrani:
        hrani = Sklad()

    for i, znak in enumerate(izraz):
        if znak in oklep:
            hrani.vstavi(znak) 

        elif znak in oklep.values():
            if hrani.prazen():
                return False  
            if oklep.get(hrani.vrh()) != znak and hrani.vrh() != "X":
                return False
            hrani.odstrani()
            
        elif znak == "X": 
            if not hrani.prazen():
                tmp = hrani.kopiraj()
                tmp.odstrani()
                if so_pravilno(izraz[i+1:],tmp, nivo+2):
                    return True
                else:
                    hrani.vstavi(znak)

    return hrani.prazen()

izraz = "(XX{X)"

if len(izraz) % 2 != 0: 
    print("Not Balanced")
elif so_pravilno(izraz):
    print("Balanced")
else:
    print("Not Balanced")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by recursively testing all possible replacements for an X:

```
def can_be_balanced(expr):
    pairs = "{}[]()"
    opening_brackets = pairs[::2]
    closing_brackets = pairs[1::2]
    closer = {o:c for o, c in zip(opening_brackets, closing_brackets)}
    opener = {c:o for o, c in zip(opening_brackets, closing_brackets)}
    
    stack = []
    for item in expr:
        if item in opening_brackets:
            # we append opening brackets to the stack
            stack.append(item)

        elif item in closing_brackets:
            if not stack or stack[-1] != opener[item]:
                # the closing bracket doesn't match the top of the stack
                return False
            else:
                # if it does, we remove the matching opening bracket
                stack.pop()
        
        elif item == 'X':
            # X could be any of the opening brackets,
            possible = list(opening_brackets)
            if stack and stack[-1] in opening_brackets:
                # or the closing bracket matching the top of the stack
                possible.append(closer[stack[-1]])
            for pos in possible:
                # we replace this X, the first one remaining in expr 
                test_expr = expr.replace('X', pos, 1)
                if can_be_balanced(test_expr):
                    # This is just in order to print the working solution we just found,
                    # you may remove these two lines
                    if not 'X' in test_expr:
                        print(test_expr)
                    
                    return True
                    
            # None of the replacements for X gave a balanced expression 
            return False
            
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid item {item} in {expr}')
    
    # The expression is balanced if and only if the stack ends up empty
    return not stack
```

Testing on your sample data:

```
tests = [("[{X}(X)]", False),
         ("{(X[X])}", True),
         ("([X}])", True),
        ]

for test in tests:
    print(test[0], ': should be', test[1])
    print(can_be_balanced(test[0]))
    print('-'*20)
```

correctly outputs (with the balanced expression in case it can be done):

```
[{X}(X)] : should be False
False
--------------------
{(X[X])} : should be True
{([[]])}
True
--------------------
([X}]) : should be True
([{}])
True
--------------------
```

Note that a major problem in your code is that you only test the end of the expression, starting at the position of the X. Beware also of [the mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) `elements=Stack()` that would leave you with the remnants of the previous call to the function instead of a fresh, empty `Stack` object.